# Fb share in phonegap App

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using the following code I can share some link on timeline successfully.
After click on share it have to be redirected to the mentioned return url (mentioned in function response under fb.ui), but it shows a BLANK PAGE in mobile.

What is my mistake? And how can I solve this?

(Note: In Browser it (redirection) works fine)

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  
     xfbml      : true,
     version    : 'v2.2'
   });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))


function fb_share(){
    FB.ui({
       method: 'feed',
       name: "Title",
       description: "description",
       link:"example.html",
       picture:"",
       message: 'Message'
    },
    function(response){
        window.location = 'example.com';
    });

}
</script>


<a onClick="fb_share()">FB SHARE </a>
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect inside your app, or open the browser app and display the page?

Comment: yes, i Want to redirect inside my app..

Answer (score 0):

The text `example.com` is not correct by itself. If you want to open the URL you should do this:

```
function(response) {
    window.location = 'example.com';
}
```

Comment: Actually i gave like this format only.. function(response) {
    window.location = 'example.com';
}  but it shows blank page still.. ( Sorry  Forget to update that previously..  )